# xib and SubUIView.class, how to add a property into that class?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, properties, xib

I create three files, there are

```
MDActionBar.h,
MDActionBar.m,
MDActionBar.xib
```

MDActionBar.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface MDActionBar : UIView{
    NSString* _type;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *label_tips;    
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* type;
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;
@end
```

MDActionBar.m

```
#import "MDActionBar.h"

@implementation MDActionBar
@synthesize type = _type;
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame withType:(NSString*)itype{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MDActionBar" owner:self options:nil];
        NSArray *theView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MDActionBar" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [theView objectAtIndex:0];
        self.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

And I use this class like this:

```
MDActionBar* mdActionBar = [[[MDActionBar alloc]initWithFrame:UI_TOOLBAR_POSITION_DOWN withType:@"done"] autorelease];
mdActionBar.type = @"done";
```

It seems there is no property named 'type' in the MDActionBar.m,

```
NSLog(@"_type %@",self.type);
```

It always show null in the console.

If I load a xib, and this xib is a UIView, and there is no 'type' property in the UIView, so that, it prints null???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At what moment do you call `NSLog(@"_type %@",self.type);`?

Comment: @JackyBoy, thanks. I call it in another method:- (IBAction)fn_pressedButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"_type %@",self.type);}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change class of view in xib from UIView to MDActionBar

Comment: I have did it in the xib, the IBOutlet works fine. but the 'type' property can't work.

Answer (score 2):

you pass type in init but never set type. you neeed store it somewhere. in init

```
self.type = itype
```

Comment: I have did it, but in another method, it print 'null', It can't keep value.